# Cilium installation on cluster created using kubeadm

Tags: kubernetes, cilium

I am trying to install Cilium (1.14) on a very vanilla k8s (1.27) cluster (1 controller + 3 workers). I used kubeadm to create the cluster on EC2 arm64 machines on AWS. The cluster works fine if I use Calico. I am using cilium install to deploy it. The Operator and Agent deployed on the control plane start fine. The agents deployed on worker nodes fail at different points to get ready. What I noticed is that they start able to reach the API server and suddenly they can't anymore. It is like something is changing at the network layer and the API server is not reachable from the worker nodes anymore.

Any suggestions are welcome.

I tried Cilium 1.14 and 1.15. I also tried deploying K8s w/o kube-proxy and let Cilium handle it. Same results.

Comment: If Calico works, why not use that?

Comment: Please add some logs of the "different points" at which failures happen.